# Archlinux :: pacman phpmyadmin returns a 404

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, archlinux

```
# pacman -S phpmyadmin
```

**Returns the following error:**

```
    Packages (2): php-mcrypt-5.6.2-2  phpmyadmin-4.2.10.1-1

Total Download Size:    5.10 MiB
Total Installed Size:   28.69 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:       28.64 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] Y
:: Retrieving packages ...
error: failed retrieving file 'phpmyadmin-4.2.10.1-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.archlinuxarm.org : The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (download library error)
```

A 404. I was unable to file normal bug report on Arch home page. So hoping someone will catch this here. Does anyone have a work around or tried Chive?

Thanks as always for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 4.2.10.1-1 is currently out of date. You need to download a fresh copy of the master package list as defined in your mirror list. As root, run:

```
pacman -Syy phpmyadmin
```

Comment: I ended up reinstalling, after not finding a direct fix.
But on repeating the same steps and doing

`~]#  pacman -Sy
 ~]#  pacman -Syu
 ~]# pacman -S phpmyadmin php-mcrypt
`

It worked.
So seems your prognosis was correct.
Thanks